# Programmatically creating SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, ios8, swrevealviewcontroller

I am creating a slide out menu on iOS using the SWRevealViewController. I am not using storyboards for this (and doing it programatically). However, the left bar button item does not show up on the screen.

The Code snippet is:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    MenuViewController *mvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Menu" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuController"];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.settingsBarButtonItem;

    self.revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:mvc frontViewController:navigationController];
    self.revealController.delegate = self;


    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.revealController;

}

-(UIBarButtonItem *) settingsBarButtonItem {

    if (!_settingsBarButtonItem ) {
        UIImage *moreImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_nav_bar_more"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        _settingsBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:moreImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

    }

    return _settingsBarButtonItem;
}
```

Comment: did you ever fix this issue, i am encountering the same issue.